# C++ creating an instance of a class

Tags: c++, oop, class, methods, overriding

```
class Game {
  private:
    string title;
    bool running;
    State currentState;

  public:
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    void setup();
    void run();
};
```

I have a variable called currentState. This is State:

```
#ifndef STATE_HPP
#define STATE_HPP

using namespace std;

class State {
  private:

  public:
    void start();
    void update();
    void render();
};

#endif
```

And then I have a class called PlayState, which inherits State:

```
#ifndef PLAY_STATE_HPP
#define PLAY_STATE_HPP

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "Game.hpp"
#include "State.hpp"

using namespace std;

class PlayState : public State {
  private:
    sf::CircleShape shape;
    Game game;

  public:
    PlayState();
    void start();
    void update();
    void render();
};

#endif
```

On my Game.cpp, I am creating currentState, by doing:

```
currentState = PlayState();
```

The problem is, though, that it's not working. currentState.update() is state.update(). It seems that I **am not overriding the State methods when I create PlayState**.

Here's PlayState.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "PlayState.hpp"

PlayState::PlayState() {
  printf("heyyy\n");
}

void PlayState::start() {
  shape.setRadius(100.f);
  shape.setOrigin(20.0f, 20.0f);
  shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
}

void PlayState::update() {
  sf::Event event;
  while (game.window.pollEvent(event)) {
    if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
      game.window.close();
      //running = false;
    }
  }

  printf("here\n");
}

void PlayState::render() {
  printf("here\n");
  game.window.clear();
  game.window.draw(shape);
  game.window.display();
}
```

Any ideas about how I can 'override' those methods? Thank you.

**EDIT**
I had to make State.cpp functions virtual so that they can be overriden.
I also had to define State *currentState as a pointer and create PlayState with "currentState = new PlayState();".
Also, now I access .update and .draw with ->update() and ->draw().

Comment: You need a virtual function in order to override anything. Anything else is just hiding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems. As @McAden said, the functions in `State` that are to be overridden in `PlayState` need to be marked virtual. The other problem is that the data member `currentState` in `Game` has type `State`. When you assign an object of type `PlayState` to it, it gets the `State` part of the `PlayState` object, but not the derived parts. This is called "slicing". To prevent it, make `currentState` a pointer to `State`, and when you create that `PlayState` object, assign its address to the `Game` object's `currentState`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the concept of virtual functions.

[Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function)

State needs:

```
virtual void update();
```

PlayState needs:

```
void update();
```

Comment: override is C++11 so you may not have that in your compiler yet.

Comment: sorry, brain fart - I've been spending too much time in C#. I corrected it.

Comment: you can not write public like that

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your function's with the virtual modifier ie.

```
virtual void Update();
```

When calling currentState->Update() this will call the topmost overridden function, if you desire to call any of the parent classes functions inside of the classes methods simply specify ie. State::Update(); when calling the function.